# How to write MOVS in terms of mov and other commands in ARM

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm working on a project where I'm trying not to use the MOVS command but a combination of MOV and other commands.

```
        mov     r3, #-2147483648
        str     r3, [r7, #36]
        mvn     r3, #-2147483648
        str     r3, [r7, #32]
        movs    r3, #0
        str     r3, [r7, #28]
        movs    r3, #0
        str     r3, [r7, #24]
```

As you can see movs is used twice here, what could be its equivalent? Possibly using ldr and mov? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried just using `mov` instead of `movs`?  Also, what variant of the ARM instruction set are you programming for?

Comment: @fuz, this is a good suggestion, but the OP hasn't shown what happens after the last `str` Are there conditions between the last `str` and and the next condition code setting instruction?  It is often the case that `movs` is the only form available for thumb and there is no choice but to use it.  It would be helpful to know the architectures  (port from -> to) or if there is some coding standard involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tst reg,reg` sets flags according to the value, so `mov dst,src` + `tst dst,dst` would be the naive drop-in replacement for any case.

Or in your case, your `str` instructions don't depend on flags so you could just use `mov r3, #0`.  (Once; reading it with `str` doesn't destroy the value so there's no need to set it again).

But if you really want to also set flags according to the `0` value, you could zero a register inefficiently with `ands r3, #0`.  (Setting to all-ones inefficiently with `orrs r3, #-1` isn't possible in ARM mode; the immediate isn't encodeable.  But it is in Thumb mode with Thumb-2 available.)

(Or `eors r3,r3` or `subs r3,r3` to borrow [the x86 zeroing idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and), but note that ARM CPUs won't special case that and run it efficiently.  In fact they're not allowed to do so: the memory-ordering model has data-dependency ordering like C++11 `std::memory_order_consume` was supposed to expose, but is otherwise weakly ordered.  `eors` and `subs`, like all ALU instructions, are guaranteed to carry a data dependency on their inputs, regardless of any special cases.)

---

For copying a register, `adds reg, reg, #0` should do the trick.  This is apparently a separate instruction with a separate opcode even in Thumb mode.

```
.syntax unified
.thumb_func
adds r1, r2, #0
movs r1, r2
```

`arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-a53 -c arm.s  && arm-none-eabi-objdump -d arm.o`

```
   0:   1c11            adds    r1, r2, #0
   2:   0011            movs    r1, r2
```

---

[Arm dedicated comparisons](https://community.arm.com/arm-community-blogs/b/architectures-and-processors-blog/posts/condition-codes-1-condition-flags-and-codes)

| Comparison | Arithmetic |
| --- | --- |
| cmp | subs |
| cmn | adds |
| tst | ands |
| teq | eors |

Ie, these four instructions perform the arithmetic equivalent, but do not write the results to a destination.  The only effect is to set condition codes, as if the arithmetic instruction was used.

In order to properly port this, it would be good to resolve what the *intent* of the original `movs` is.  It is quite possible that the condition codes are not needed and this was a limitation of the architecture the code was originally targeting.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use tst in my project, do you know of any other combination that might work?

Comment: @Charlieglider: I assume `cmp reg, #0` also sets flags the same as `tst`, or even `adds reg, #0`.  I don't know ARM well enough to be 100% certain there isn't some obscure difference in a seldom-used flag, but you could check with a debugger.

Comment: I think the `tst` versus `cmp` goes to the intent here.  Ie, what exactly are the condition codes being used for.  From the given assembler sequence it is not clear.  If they are used, I think only the 'Z' bit would be tested.  But really I think it is a vestige of a thumb encoding the OP has to port.  Ie, there was no plain `mov` in the thumb1 ISA.  If this is the case, a simple `mov` will suffice.